# How to get rid of Error on launching Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Yesterday I set up Eclipse and created 2 Java projects in it. I am running Eclipse 4.7 for Mac OS X, Oxygen 3A. Today I created an alias in my Applications for Eclipse, copied it to my Desktop in Mac and then removed both the alias. After that whenever I try to launch Eclipse I get this error which says

```
An error occurred. See the log file /Users/<user>/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log.
```

Please inform what i should do at the earliest so that i may proceed with my work

I have done all steps in Google:

1. edited eclipse.ini to include -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin,
2. deleted .metadata folder,
3. removed an early version of java jdk folder jdk-10.0.1.jdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m1YD.png)

Here are log file contents: 
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19PcF8Zvf7cQgHQDUmc_0M6G-KTCeI4U4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do what it says and look in the .log file. [edit] your question and show us what it says there. Without the contents of the .log file we can't help. Note that on macOS the .metadata folder and the .log file are hidden so you will have to tell Finder to show hidden files (Shift+Command+.)

Comment: Please look at the error in  /Users/preetinderkaurvirk/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.log and copy/paste the exact test into your post.

Comment: You cannot run Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) with Java 11 (in Java 11 some packages have been removed that are required by Eclipse versions that have been released before Java 11). Use Java 8 (probably 9 or 10 should also work) to run Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) or even better use Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10). You shouldn't delete the `.metadata` folder. If possible, restore the `.metadata` folder.

Comment: Added logfile contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I uninstalled jdk 11 and Eclipse works fine with jdk 10.

Thanks all!!

Marking this resolved